# Registering applications in Azure AD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

To use REST APIs available in Microsoft Graph, I have registered the application in Azure AD and have added API permissions. I have opted to use the delegated permissions and not application permissions.

Is it mandatory that these privileges are granted by an admin before the application can use the REST API.

Please advise.

Regards,
Meena

Comment: Depends on the permissions - before you can access the api-endpoints you need to have a user logged in, when you are using delegated permissions. some permissions need admin consent, some others dont. 
read herer for a start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Answer (score 0):

For the apps with delegated permissions scenario, either the user or an administrator consents to the permissions that the app requests, and the app is delegated permission to act as the signed-in user when making calls to the target resource. Some delegated permissions can be consented to by non-administrative users, but some higher-privileged permissions require administrator consent. To learn which administrator roles can consent to delegated permissions, see [Administrator role permissions in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#available-roles).

**For Reference,**

Please go through the below [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent) and the below key points,

1. [Requesting individual user consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-individual-user-consent)
2. [Requesting consent for an entire tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-consent-for-an-entire-tenant)
3. [Admin-restricted permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#admin-restricted-permissions)
4. [Using the admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint)

Comment: Hi Hari, Thanks for the response.

Comment: If the purpose is to read, write or delete files, is it mandatory to have admin consent. Or would a consent from file owners be sufficient. In this case the application is requesting for the following API permission - user.read, site.read.all

Comment: Yes for a normal user require admin consent .